# creating js plugin that is immutable and stores one piece of data

Tags: javascript, immutability

I am building a simple javascript plugin that I wish to be completely immutable.

ie.

```
plugin.use('soap');
plugin.wash() ===> //soap
```

The only way i can think to do this is by setting a variable array

```
var use = []
function use(cleaner){
use.push(cleaner)
}

function wash(){
return use[0];
}
```

But this is not immutable. I know that one solution is to simply return a version of the plugin with the 'use' information embedded as a constant, but I also need it to be accessible across an entire application by name (ie. import plugin from 'plugin')

is this possible?

Comment: That isn't clear at all

Comment: But `use` is a mutating function by definition, how do you want that to be immutable?

Comment: Solved problem: http://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/

Comment: @Amit all I know is that you can have completely immutable applications, so I feel like this should be possible.

Comment: @Jared Farrish i don't see how immutablejs solves this issue. Can you explain?

Comment: Well, use immutable.js instead of an array. Presto, chango, immutable.